# How to combine two lambda functions into one?

Tags: python, lambda

Say I have:

```
f1 = lambda x: 2*x+2
f2 = lambda x: x**2
```

and I want to create `f3 = x**2 + 2*x + 2`, by combining `f1` and `f2`.
How do I do that in Python?

Comment: Beware: suppose you have  `f1 = lambda x: 1/x` and `f2 = lambda x: -1/x`. Would you want `f3a = lambda x: 0` or `f3b = lambda x: 1/x - 1/x` as the result? (Note that `f3a(0)` and `f3b(0)` are *not* the same.)

Answer (score 10):

How about creating a third `lambda` like so:

```
f1= lambda x: 2*x+2
f2= lambda x: x**2

g = lambda a: f1(a) + f2(a)
print(g(2))  # prints -> 10
```

Comment: Also, note that pep8 discourage to assign lambda to variables.
It is preferred to use `def` instead. (Binding a function to a reference _is_ the purpose of `def`)

Comment: if you're running multiple types of checks from a check function and returning a function to call then putting a def is really just unnecessary clutter... And python was meant to be human-readable right? Not to mention, lambda functions were created for a reason, no?