# How to add multivariable functions in python

Tags: python

May I know how should I add two functions(Multivariable).
For example,

```
T=lambda t,y: [0,t] 
P=lambda t,y: [y,y]
```

what is the proper way to get `T-P` because when I tried, it gives an error message
"unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'function'".

At first I mulitvariable case will also follow the same case as it is for single variable. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)) but it doesn't work.

And I apologize for putting my question as a single variable function earlier

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine two lambda functions into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806354/how-to-combine-two-lambda-functions-into-one)

Comment: Thank you @AvishkaKavinduB.Dambawinna

Comment: I don't know what you trying to archive, but you can do this also `f = lambda x, y: x**2+y**3` and pass two parameters to **x** and **y** , `f(2,2)`

Comment: Thank you for the comment @AvishkaDambawinna .. 
What I really need to do is: 
I have two multivariable functions  
 
`T=lambda t,y: [0,t]` and 
`P=lambda t,y: [y,y]`

And I need to have a third function that gets the addition of T and P. But seems like it dosen't work

Comment: In that case above method cannot be used

Comment: Have you got any suggestions

Comment: What do you mean by minus for lists `[0,t]` and `[y,y]`? Can you provide the desired behavior for the function `T-P`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
f = lambda x: f1(x) + f2(x)
```

If you want to add functions with arbitrary arguments you can define a solution like this:

```
def add_functions(f1, f2):
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        return f1(*args, **kwargs) + f2(*args, **kwargs)
    return f
```

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. 
Your first suggestion would do my job. Anyway can you tell me what does *args and **kwargs means

Comment: You are welcome. You can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: What I really needed to do is: 
I have two multivariable functions  
 
`T=lambda t,y: [0,t]` and 
`P=lambda t,y: [y,y]`

And I want to have a third function that gets the addition of T and P. But seems like it dosen't work

Comment: Can you, please, update your question give the certain result you expect from the addition of the functions?

Answer (score 0):

```py
f = lambda x, y: x + y
# f(2, 3) = 2 + 3 = 5 
g = lambda x, y: x * y
# g(2, 3) = 2 * 3 = 6 
h = lambda x, y: f(x, y) + g(x, y)
# h(2, 3) = f(2, 3) + g(2, 3) = (2 + 3) + (2 * 3) = 5 + 6 = 11
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. See How to Answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem, I guess the only way would be a third function.
Like this:

```py
f3 = lambda x,y: f1(x) + f2(y)
```